# MacBook Air 2018 vs. MacBook Pro: What is the battery life at equal brightness in nits?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, screen

The MacBook Air 2018 is advertised as 12 hours battery life, the MacBook Pro as 10 hours. This official Apple testing is done using 3/4 brightness setting. Since the maximum brightness of both models differs (300 vs 400 nits). I.e. the testing is at 3/4 * 300=225 nits on the MacBook Air and 3/4 * 500=375 nits on the MacBook Pro.

Which model has better battery life when both screens are set to the same brightness at 250 nits?

Comment: I just happened to catch this [video review](https://youtu.be/xRDgVS5KZ_E?t=489) that directly answers this question.  I started the video at 8:10 where they talk about battery life, but feel free to see the whole review.

Comment: That is amazing - thank you. The video calculates (in that test) 10 hours (-1 min) for the MacBook Pro vs. 11 hours (+6 min) for the MacBook Air, so rather than a 20% difference (with the Air lasting 20% longer), there is still a difference, but only 10% (an extra hour for the MacBook Air). Thanks for this!

Comment: Feel free to write up an answer and I'll be sure to upvote.

Comment: Their advertising has nothing to do with reality. I used to get 8 hours when I got MBA 2013 (advertised as 12h) and with the new MBA 2018 I get just 6 hours. And my screen brightness is 50%, doing just web browsing. I have no idea how did they achieve these 12 hours to be honest.